# making middle block height 100% while vertical neighbours are fixed

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to make "shadow-repeat block" height 100%, while "shadow-up" is aligned to top, "shadow-down" to bottom, both fixed height, e.g. 200px

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="right-shadow">
        <div class="shadow-up"></div>
        <div class="shadow-repeat"></div>
        <div class="shadow-down"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="content">
        </div><!--content-->
    <div class="left-shadow">
        <div class="shadow-up"></div>
        <div class="shadow-repeat"></div>
        <div class="shadow-down"></div>
    </div>
</div><!--center-->
```

As for now I don't get the right result. 
If there is a way to make it right, please help.

```
.left-shadow{
    width: 22px;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: -22px;
    top:0px;
    height: 100%;
}
.right-shadow .shadow-up{
    background: url('img/shadow-part-one.png') no-repeat -22px 0px transparent;
    height: 257px;
}
.right-shadow .shadow-repeat{
    height: 100%;
    background: url('img/shadow-part-two.png') repeat-y -22px 0px transparent;
}
.right-shadow .shadow-down{
    background: url('img/shadow-part-three.png') repeat-y -22px 0px transparent;
    height: 260px;
}
.center{
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.content{
    float: left;
    width: 1100px;
}
```

Comment: What sort of CSS have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

**CSS:**

```
    .center{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
}
.right-shadow{
    float:right;
    background:blue;
}
.left-shadow{
    float:left;
    background:green;
}
.shadow-up{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
}
.shadow-down{
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}
.right-shadow .shadow-up{
    float:right;
}
.right-shadow .shadow-down{
    float:right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="right-shadow">
        <div class="shadow-up"></div>
        <div class="shadow-repeat">right content</div>
        <div class="shadow-down"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-shadow">
        <div class="shadow-up"></div>
        <div class="shadow-repeat">left content</div>
        <div class="shadow-down"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="content">Here is some content</div><!--content-->
</div><!--center-->
```

Comment: If you provide example code, please separate HTML and CSS. It's easy and better readable..

Comment: if we add more content in "content", "shadow-repeat" will not scale, unfortunately

Comment: The easy fix is to make .shadow-repeat clear:both and set the height manually. I'll look into it later today if I have time.

Comment: The thing is, that I need "shadow-up" to be header, and "shadow-down" - footer in both "right-shadow" and "left-shadow". And "shadow-repeat" should depend on the height of "content" block

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand your question, I believe you're going for a three column layout, where the middle column is always 100% of its parent, and the side columns can take on any height.  I've abstracted your markup pretty heavily for this answer, so you're going to have to translate it back, but it will achieve your goal.

**HTML**

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="left-shadow">
    </div>

    <div class="right-shadow">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the two shadow divs have been moved on top of the content area.  We're going to float the shadows to the left and right, effectively removing them from the flow (for our purposes, anyway).  Floated elements aren't *pushy* like normal block elements; they have a position, but other block elements won't be pushed down the page by them (inline elements are a different story).  Floated elements **can**, however be pushed by existing block elements, therefore we want to declare them above the content area which would otherwise push them down.

**CSS**

```
.center
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #333333;
}

.left-shadow
{
    background-color: pink;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
}

.right-shadow
{
    background-color: green;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right;
}

.content
{
    margin-right: 320px;
    margin-left: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Effectively what we're doing is floating the side boxes left and right, then setting margins on the middle box such that it doesn't overlap with the sides.  It can be a little tricky to wrap your head around at first, but it's pretty solid.  Since our middle element is now an unfloated block, we can easily set a height on it of 100%.  Similarly the sides can be set to whatever height you want them to be (or just to have their contents height!).